# ngx-gallery not displaying image

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, image-gallery

I am using `@ngx-gallery/lightbox` to display an image gallery. But it does not display any images. This I provide some code and [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qytkkw) demo as your reference

**HTML**

```
<button mat-button (click)="lightbox.open(0, 'lightbox')">Open Gallery</button>
```

**Component**

```
 items: GalleryItem[];

  constructor(public gallery: Gallery, public lightbox: Lightbox) {

  }
 ngOnInit() {
    // This is for Basic example
    this.items = imageData.map(item => {
      return new ImageItem(item.srcUrl, item.previewUrl);
    });

    // This is for Lightbox example
    this.gallery.ref('lightbox').load(this.items);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like you have not initialised ImageItem properly, try this

```
this.items = imageData.map(item => new ImageItem({ src: item.srcUrl, thumb: item.previewUrl }));
```

instead of

```
this.items = imageData.map(item => {
      return new ImageItem(item.srcUrl, item.previewUrl);
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that the `ImageItem` class expects a single parameter in form of an object.

This should fix your issue:

```
this.items = imageData.map(item => {
      return new ImageItem({ src: item.srcUrl, thumb: item.previewUrl });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what api u were reading from, but [according to their official api](https://github.com/MurhafSousli/ngx-gallery/wiki/Gallery-Usage#by-accessing-galleryref), [this demo should work](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-whue3k)